# JMeter - 403 forbidden response

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, performance-testing

I have URL: http://******-********-management.*********.net.s3-website-**-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/session/signin.

I have created HTTP request sampler and my test plan looks like:

[image: View Results Tree - Result]
[image: View Results Tree - Response headers]
[image: eView Results Tree - Request]

Before sign-in the test, even the login page is not showing. For login I get HTTP 403 forbidden error.

Comment: I see a distinct lack of specified headers for your call. You might want to look at the aws authentication docs.

Comment: HTTP 403 means the credentials is correct but the client does not has acces to resource. Can you check if the access key you are using has access to the particular endpoint.

Comment: @Mukesh Tiwari, They don't provide me any access key all they give me only is S3 website endpoint for testing. I asked the concerned developer for checking that: all the Objects in the bucket must be publicly accessible. 2) it is not encrypted with  AWS-KMS key 3) The bucket policy must allow access to s3: GetObject.
If the bucket policy grants public access, the AWS account that owns the bucket must also own the object.  The requested objects must exist in the bucket. they say that all objects are publicly accessible and there is no encryption also. then why I am getting this 403 response. p

Comment: I have solved the issue by making some changes in the path of the URL.

Comment: Hi don't share sensitive information , your screen shot has url and other sensitive informations